# Why is IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent contacting a Charter IP address

Tags: messages, mojave, dns, malware, tcp

I never use iMessage. I never use iCloud. And yet I happened to check my Mac's current network connections and I found this:

```
IMRemoteURLConn 33557 me    7u  IPv4 ...
   0t0  TCP 192.168.1.198:57996->
            107.14.47.74:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Note that 107.14.47.74 is a Charter ISP address, not Apple's.

Notice that it is trying to contact it on port 80 (HTTP).

So I try this:

```
$ wget 107.14.47.74
--2019-02-07 22:05:25--  http://107.14.47.74/
Connecting to 107.14.47.74:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2019-02-07 22:05:25 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

Why would a random Charter IP address have a web server running? In fact, you can try any IP in that subnet and each one has a web server running.

Note that we are Charter customers but our IP is different, it's 104.172.x.x.

UPDATE

In Terminal I used "sudo log show | less"  and searched for 107.14.47 ...
It turns out this is init-p01st.push.apple.com.
So Apple has put a push server in Charter's range... in theory.

Pinging it shows akamai.net however, not Charter, so this still looks fishy.